MIPLIB 2024 submission are open
Roughly every seven years, a new edition of the main dataset of Mixed-Integer programs is released. The last edition was MIPLIB 2017, extensively used to benchmark solver and algorithmic performance. MIPLIB is vital for MIP-solving to develop.
Given the already submitted instances, there is a higher demand for MIPs arising from applications (but academic instances are of course still welcome). Regarding difficulty, it's better if instances aren't trivial (>10s to optimality), but also not extremely hard (can be solved by at least one solver in <8h). It is also desirable if the problem has friendly numerics (e.g., no huge difference in the order of magnitude of the coefficients).
If you have some instances that you feel fit these criteria, please consider submitting them at https://miplibsubmissions.zib.de/
Submissions are open until December 31st.

Apologies for this not being like the usual questions in this forum, but MIPLIB is something that the whole OR community benefits from. For this reason, and for me not being involved with the project, I wouldn't count it as self-promotion.

I'd argue that problems with bad numerics and/or that can't be solved by any solver are even more useful (since that's what happens in practice), but maybe that's just me.

There is room for open instances, yes, MIPLIB 2017 has ~21% of them. I think the incentive is to discourage problems where their difficulty comes from being excessively large, but rather they have an interesting structure, and also to make benchmarking easier. As for the numerics, I'm just guessing, but it may be because it has a larger impact on LP-solving, not necessarily MIP-solving. Most MIP-people I know wouldn't enjoy having to deal with tons of floating point errors to develop their work.

Will the "friendly numerics" aspect be used as a filtering mechanism during the problem selection?
I wanted to submit some instances where the coefficients are not too friendly, but the instances are not very difficult either (solved in <1h, typically).

oh fancy seeing you here, @RobertSchwarz! No, I don't think it will be, it's more of a preference. As stated earlier, unfriendly numerics can also be important, so they wouldn't be a disqualifying factor.
